# Why the find command must run with '&'?

Tags: visual-foxpro

I'm a Chinese student.First of all,my English is very poor.LOL~~~
I'm very puzzled about some syntax rule of Visualfox Pro.

There is a character field called id in my table, run the command below to locate the record that it's id equals 'A0001':

```
index on id tag _id
id='A0001'
find &id
```

&id return a variable name A0001,I just wanna know how the interpreter compares the variable name with the character field in the table??

For the above code, it can also be rewritten like below:

```
find A0001
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a variable with the same name as a field in the currently-selected table, the field's contents will be used when referring to the variable.  You can avoid this by prefixing with 'm.' (meaning to use the memory variable rather than the field).  So do this:

`id = 'A001'   && assignment always goes to the variable`

`SEEK m.id`

One way the & technique could be useful is if you want to refer to one of several values:

`id1 = 'A001'`

`id2 = 'B002'`

`to_find = 'm.id2'`

`SEEK &to_find    && Acts like: SEEK m.id2`

Comment: In VFP 6.0.It seems that the find command Can only run with a variable names, not strings.For example:Find A0001.
That will locate the record that It's value of id fields equals 'A0001'.Whats your vf p version?

Comment: @LILPIGGY Ah, I see.  I've never actually used the FIND command (and I have been programming in this language and its earlier versions since 1988).  I always thought it was the same as SEEK.  FIND is deprecated, you should use SEEK instead. I'll edit my answer to use SEEK.

Comment: Uha,In my country,Although the FIND command may be a deprecated command,but it still appear in the exam.Thanks for your answer~

Answer (score -1):

It's all about how Compilers and Interpreters works. They shared the same 3 steps:

> - Step 1 (called Lexical Analysis): The compiler breaks the submitted source code into meaningful elements called lexemes and generates a
>     sequence of tokens from the lexemes.
> - Step 2 (called Syntax Analysis): The compiler uses the sequence of tokens generated during the lexical analysis to generate a tree-like
>     data structure called Abstract Syntax Tree, AST
> - Step 3 (called Semantic Analysis): The compiler uses the AST generated during syntax analysis to check if the program is consistent
>     with all the rules of the source programming language

So, "&" is an symbol so they can recognize it's a VARIABLE, not finding a string name "id"

Comment: '&' operator in VFP is used to define a Macro.It works like '#define' in c. So,Your answer may not be What i want. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The & operator is not like #DEFINE. #DEFINE specifies a compile-time substitution. & is a run-time substitution.

Comment: You are right.I mean,the two operators are similar But  not the same.